# slideDown is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

why this is not working:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
if($(".alert").is(":hidden")) {
  $(".alert").slideDown(500, function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {
          $(this).remove(); 
      });
    }, 4000);
  });
}  
}, 1000);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="login-error" class="container alert alert-danger" role="alert" hidden>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong>Error!</strong> Invalid login or password!
      </div>
```

It is not sliding down, and the element is deleted after 4 seconds.

How to fix, help, please. Thank You!

Comment: jquery animation methods don't modify/read the hidden attribute. Use display css styling instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works correctly in JS Fiddle...

https://jsfiddle.net/d186qkfb/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.setTimeout(function() {   
    if($(".alert").is(":hidden")) {
      $(".alert").slideDown(500, function() {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function() {
              $(this).remove(); 
          });
        }, 4000);
      });
    }  
  }, 1000);
});
```